# How to calculate left shift for big powers?

Tags: bitwise-operators

In order to perform left shift, we have to multiply the left operand with the 2^second operand.
For big powers How to perform left shift manually?

For small numbers such as 3<<1
It will work as 3 * 2^1 = 3 * 2 = 6.

But i am stuck here that how to calculate manually 40<<34.

To perform 2^34 is so time consuming.
Is there any other way to calculate left shift with big powers?

Comment: Write 40 in binary, then write 34 zeros after it - there's your answer (in binary, but the result of a bit shift isn't particularly meaningful if viewed in decimal).

Comment: Are you asking how to do it on paper, or in a programming language? If a programming language, which one, and why doesn't the language's shift operators work for you? If you're asking how to do it by hand on paper, that's off-topic here; this site is about programming.

Comment: @yshavit yes because for preparation of the exam we have to do that on paper

Comment: I would take @jasonharper's advice then, slightly modified: write it out as binary, add the 0s to do the shift, and then convert that binary back to decimal (assuming you need it in decimal for the exam).